# How to get content with their taxonomy term name and id?

Tags: theming, 8, taxonomy-terms

Hello I have created content type product. I also add Taxonomy with name "category". I add field in with term reference in product content type.
Now I want to get all content with taxonomy name and id which have  content type named "product" using query in Drupal 8 .

Comment: See \Drupal\Core\Entity\Query\QueryInterface::condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a dynamic query like this:

```
$query = \Drupal::database()->select('node_field_data', 'nfd');
$query->condition('nfd.type', 'product');
$query->leftJoin('node__field_category', 'ft', 'ft.entity_id = nfd.nid');
$query->leftJoin('taxonomy_term_field_data', 'fd', 'fd.tid = ft.field_category_target_id');
$query->fields('fd', ['tid', 'name']);
$query->fields('nfd', ['nid']);
$results = $query->execute()->fetchAll();
```

Suppose the reference field taxonomy machine name is "node__field_category".
The result of the query will be node id , term name and term id.